# Как передать изображение строкой в PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl

Как передать изображение на сторонний api через PHP если в документации написано
[image: Фото из документации]
Вот код:

```
function uploadFile($url, $path)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    if (class_exists('\CURLFile'))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['image' => new \CURLFile($path)]);
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['image' => "@$path"]);
    }
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // return json_decode($data, true);
    return $data;
}

echo uploadFile("https://trace.moe/api/search", "img/image.jpg");
```

Ответ сервера `"No image received"`

Comment: дак попробовали искать "_php base64 encode_" ?

Comment: [`$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-encode.php)